# Need Jar file to read JSON array returned in response, having all these three types JSONObject,JSONParse,JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I searched on net, but didn't find any jar file having all these type , although for deserializing JSON object every one is using these types..

Can any one who had used these types give me the path to download the jar file

Or any other good example to deserialize JSON data.

I am new to java, from .net, developing application for android.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Android has a inbuilt support for JSON so you don't need to add extra jar for it.**

Look at [org.json](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)

and Tutorial [JSON in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)

For java - this is [download link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/json-lib-2.4/json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar/download?use_mirror=space) and also [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/)

Comment: Thank , actually I am testing my code with Java console application, need Jar file for that.

Comment: In which android version 2.1?

Comment: The org.json api's have been included in Android since api version 1.